# How do I mount an `img` created with /bin/dd of a hard drive?

Tags: mount, dd

I used `dd` to backup a **80GB** drive

```
dd if=/dev/sdb of=~/sdb.img
```

Now I need to access some files on that drive, but I don't want to copy the ".img" back over the drive.

`mount ~/sdb.img /mnt/sdb` doesn't work either. It returns :

```
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
```

I tried to find the filesystem type with `file -s`

```
fox@shoebox $ file -s sdb.img
sdb.img: x86 boot sector; partition 1: ID=0x12, starthead 1, startsector 63, 10233342 sectors; partition 2: ID=0xc, active, starthead 0, startsector 10233405, 72517410 sectors; partition 3: ID=0xc, starthead 0, startsector 82750815, 73545570 sectors, code offset 0xc0
```

Is it possible to mount `sdb.img`, or must I use `dd` to restore the drive?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When you use `dd` on `/dev/sdb` instead of `/dev/sdb1` or `/dev/sdb2`, you copy **all** the *partitions* from the said drive into **one** file.

You must mount each partition separately.

---

To **mount** a partition from a **file**, you must first find out where in the file that partition resides.

Using your output from `file -s sdb.img` we find the `startsectors` for each partition:

> sdb.img: x86 boot sector; **partition 1**:
>   ID=0x12, starthead 1, **startsector 63**,
>   10233342 sectors; **partition 2**: ID=0xc,
>   active, starthead 0, **startsector
>   10233405**, 72517410 sectors; **partition
>   3**: ID=0xc, starthead 0, **startsector
>   82750815**, 73545570 sectors, code
>   offset 0xc0

**Partition**     **Startsector**
1                   63
2                   10233405
3                   82750815

To mount a single partition, where `X`  is the **startsector** of that partition, run:

```
mount ~/sdb.img /mnt/sdb -o offset=$((X*512))
```

So to mount  the **second partition**, you will have to run:

```
mount ~/sdb.img /mnt/sdb2 -o offset=$((10233405*512))
```

**sidenote:** make sure that `/mnt/sdb2` exists before you run this.

Have fun!

---

**update:** In the answer, I assumed that the sector size for you image was `512`, please see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2668/finding-the-sector-size-of-a-partition) on how to calculate that.

Comment: You can also get the startsectors in a tabular format using `file -l sdb.img` as posted in the answer of your question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2668/finding-the-sector-size-of-a-partition

Comment: @student: Only a correction for future readers: That would be `fdisk -l` not `file -l`.

Comment: Further clarification - you can get the number of 512 byte sectors by adding the -u option to that command - so `fdisk -u -l sdb.img`

Comment: If your version of `file` is less talkative by default, try adding the `-k` switch to get the kind of output shown in the answer – like this: `file -k FILENAME.img`.

Answer (score 12):

On Linux mount commands within the [accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2661/how-do-i-mount-an-img-created-with-bin-dd-of-a-hard-drive/2662#2662) will implicitly create a loop device. Assuming the the full disk image has a correct partition table (which your kernel is able to understand), you may prefer to use [`losetup(8)`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/mount/losetup.8.en.html) directly to save you the hassle of calculating offsets. Also there is no need for extra tools like `kpartx` as suggest in an other [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2661/how-do-i-mount-an-img-created-with-bin-dd-of-a-hard-drive/325140#325140). It will do basically the same thing as the following:

`losetup -Prf sdb.img` will associate the first free loop device (`-f`) as readonly (`-r`) with the image file `sdb.img`. The `-P` option forces the kernel to scan the partition table of this loop device and will create loop devices for each partition.

So you may get something like:

```
$ lsblk
NAME      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0       7:0    0 167.7G  1 loop
├─loop0p1 259:0    0   500M  1 loop
└─loop0p2 259:1    0 167.2G  1 loop
...
```

You can now mount each partition, readonly of course, at a desired mountpoint.

```
$ mount -r /dev/loop0p1 /tmp/backup_sdb1
```

Keeping everything readonly is optional, but may be a good thing to do for a backup image.

**update:** [`-P` option was added](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/commit/?id=916bf85e621bb01d58279a014088376c80050a74) with util-linux-2.21 in 2012. So it was not available at the time the accepted answer was written. Also note this and the other answers are specific to linux. OpenBSD and NetBSD have vnode disks managed by [`vnconfig(8)`](https://man.openbsd.org/man8/mount_vnd.8) and FreeBSD has memory disks managed by [`mdconfig(8)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mdconfig&sektion=8).

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can use a nice tool called `kpartx`. From the man page:

> kpartx - Create device maps from partition tables

This means that you can make a "pseudo device", with device partitions, right from the img file:

```
$ kpartx -av sdb.img
add map loop0p1 (254:2): 0 2048 linear /dev/loop0 0
add map loop0p2 (254:3): 0 31162 linear /dev/loop0 2048
$ lsblk
.
.
.
loop0                     7:0    0  16.2M  0 loop
├─loop0p1               254:2    0     1M  0 part
└─loop0p2               254:3    0  15.2M  0 part
```

Then you can mount `/dev/mapper/loop0p2` for example, if you want the second partition on the image.