# Read files after running ddrescue

Tags: data-recovery, ddrescue

I have run ddrescue on a hard disk, and got all data (2 partition) to another disk 
named part1.img and part2.img. How to proceed to read (list) the files in part2.img?
I use fedora 14, 32 bit

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I mount an \`img\` created with /bin/dd of a hard drive?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2661/how-do-i-mount-an-img-created-with-bin-dd-of-a-hard-drive)

Comment: Sorry.. that deals with a more complex case. I actually can't find a dupe of this. They are all slightly more esoteric.

Comment: If you have the partitions (contrary to the whole disk), you should be able to loop mount the partitions in directory: `mkdir part1; mount part1.img part1 -o loop,ro` (read only to prevent breaking something in case there is a problem).

Answer (score 0):

To mount a partition image

As `root` run:

```
mkdir $mount_path
mount -t $filesystem_type -o loop $image_file $mount_path
```

In your case this will most likely be

```
mkdir /mnt/part1
mount -t ext4 -o loop part1.img /mnt/part1
```

As Anthon suggested you may want to add the `ro` mount option to prevent anything from changing.

Comment: In most cases, you could even omit the `-t` parameter and let the kernel detect the file system type